# Connecting to mongoDB from bash shell script

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell, unix

I am trying to connect to a remote MongoDB instance using a shell script, but I am not able to connect.

```
  #!/bin/sh

mongo --eval "db = connect('sm-repository2.db.qa.test.com:27017/testdb')"

mongo --eval "db.stats()"  # do a simple harmless command of some sort

RESULT=$?   # returns 0 if mongo eval succeeds

if [ $RESULT -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "mongodb not running"
    exit 1
else
    echo "mongodb running!"
fi
```

This tries to connect to my local mongo instance and gives me this error :

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84`
```

Comment: Could be an escape sequence issue?  Can you try `mongo --eval "db = connect('sm-repository2.db.qa.test.com:27017/testdb')"`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But that doesn't help.

Comment: May be it's because you are opening 2 separate mongo shells?  Can you try passing all javascript code in one mongo shell command?  If not can you add log statements to confirm which line is exactly failing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want is:

```
 mongo sm-repository2.db.qa.test.com:27017/testdb --eval "db.stats()"
```

Or for longer scripts:

```
 mongo sm-repository2.db.qa.test.com:27017/testdb script.js
```

See the full options in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/).